# How to set an image in a marker snippet on map

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a simple program that shows a marker on the map. On my marker I've already set an image and my code is this:

```
private GoogleMap Mymarker;
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Mymarker = googleMap;
        LatLng markerPosition = new LatLng(Lat, Long);
        BitmapDrawable dr = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image);
        Bitmap bitmapD = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(dr.getBitmap(), 200, 200, false);
        Mymarker.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().snippet("My Snippet").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapD)).position(markerPosition).title("Marker"));
        Mymarker.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(markerPosition));
    }
```

Now I wanna make a description in my marker's snippet, which shows another image. It's possible? How can I make it?